# How to export emma coverage to HTML in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, emma, eclipse-juno

I'm using Eclipse Juno and I want to get Emma code coverage. Right now I am getting the coverage in coverage window of Eclipse. But what should I do if I want the full coverage in HTML format. Previously when I was using indigo, I was having an option called export coverage to HTML. Now I don't see such an option here.

Answer (score 4):

In the coverage view, after running a coverage session, I can right-click on the project and there's an "Export Session..." option. This gives me a dialog for exporting as an HTML report.

- EclEmma Feature (2.1.4.201208011137)
- Eclipse (Version: Juno Release, Build id: 20120614-1722)

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972099/eclemma-not-offering-report-exportation-option)

1. Right click, and select "Export Session".
2. Type "report" and you can find the "coverage report" option.
3. Click "next"
4. You can get the Export report panel where you can choose the report type

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with the maven emma plugin:

```
http://emma.sourceforge.net/maven-emma-plugin/
```

*If you aren't familiar with Maven...this might not be the simplest solution, but definitely is fairly 'standard' as far as I know. :)

Comment: *I realize this isn't "the way it was before", but you might find it useful in the long term. :)

Comment: OP is not asking about a maven alternative..

Comment: they want to export html coverage reports from within eclipse.  I use maven to achieve this from within eclipse, using the maven emma plugin.  Not only is it easy to produce these reports from within the eclipse gui, this same method can be used from the command line and/or jenkins,etc.

seems like a pretty good solution.

Comment: @CasualIT I know it's more useful etc but that's not what is asked

Comment: they asked how to export html coverage reports via the eclipse gui.  This can be achieved in 2 ways: 

1.  Via emma eclipse integration
2.  Via maven eclipse integration