# Eclemma not offering report exportation option

Tags: eclipse, export, code-coverage, eclemma

I'm sure that I'm making some kind of rookie mistake, but I'm using EclEmma for the first time right now and can't figure out, despite checking numerous guides, how to export my coverage report.  For reference, this is on Windows 8 x64 and using Eclipse Kepler (let me know if you need any more information than that).

I can see that the EclEmma has successfully run, and I can get into and play with the Coverage view as below:

[image: View of EclEmma]

However, right-clicking anywhere in the report offers only an option to "Export Session," never "Export Report," and going through my File -> Export dialog doesn't seem to do any better.  I tried exporting the session as XML and a few different configurations, but it never got the code coverage report that I was looking for.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or need to ensure before I can export it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As you do before, click right button and select "Export Session".
2. Type "report" and you can find the "coverage report" option.
3. Click "next"
4. You can get the Export report panel.

Comment: Works for me as  a first step, but is there no way to do this automatically after each run configured in the CoverageConfiguration?